# "No operator block for your host" error while trying to auth IRC bot

Tags: irc

I'm creating an IRC bot, and I want it to auth("login" to the server), with the OPER message.
But when I send it, I receive the "No operator block for your host" error, its error code is 491.
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You should check that your hostname/ip address matches that in the O-Line for the IRC server.

Operator permissions are restricted not only by password and username, but also by one or more hostnames.